# 11 open review cases, none shown?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

Are any of you familiar with these "ghost review cases" which show up in the header counter, but not in the list of reviews?

[image: Ghost review cases.]

Answer (score 1):

The overlords at stackoverflow have explained this in the past, I had the same question. Basically that's the total open items, not just for you. Apparently the rationale is that to do it per-person (so your number is for you and my number is for me) would be too server intensive.

We're supposed to view it as an overall indicator of how well the site is keeping up with incidents that need attention.

It's a little screwy, but that's the deal.

Comment: This is correct. Note, if you open the queue and complete the available review tasks, that number in the menu bar will decrease. It's only if there are no open items at all for anyone that it will not appear.